# Insert and Update with AES_ENCRYPT is mangling character set on double byte script

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, utf-8

DB and fields are UTF8_unicode_ci collation - MySql v 5.6

HTML charset is utf 8

Double byte script was entered successfully prior to this issue (Chinese, Japanese, plus Cyrillic etc) when using plain non encrypted input.

But trying to use AES_ENCRYPT on input mangles all non-english script.
DB field is BLOB.

```
 UPDATE mytable SET bodytext=AES_ENCRYPT('任車心是，防少劇和的；子反華不就','aeskey') WHERE t_id=123
```

produces strings of question marks - English is fine though

I'm not sure if I should try to CONVERT the input to UTF8 first - but when I try that I get an error.
Any suggestions of what to review?

Comment: Which DBMS is this? MySQL? SQL Server? And which version? You should tag the question with this info as different DBMSes and versions behave differently.

Comment: What do you mean by "double byte script"?

Answer (score -1):

Forcing utf8mb4 does the trick. Run a query against MySQL immediately after making the connection with:

[`SET NAMES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-names.html)`'utf8mb4';`

Alternatively, use these settings in your my.cnf file to get the same effect:

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

(Note: These settings are defaults (for the most part) in MySQL 8.0 and MariaDB 10.3, so this probably isn't a problem there.)

Chinese (and other) scripts are multibyte - standard utf8 allows 3 bytes per character - fine for plain text but using AES_ENCRYPT ON 3 bytes requires another byte - thus setting utf8mb4 allows the required 4 bytes per character.

Comment: Can you clarify how this solves the problem, and where it's applied?

Comment: Updated the answer - I'm not used to answering my own questions so not sure why I got the downvotes.

Comment: What?  AES_ENCRYPT does not look at characters.  It looks at byte strings.  You need `utf8mb4` because some Chinese characters are 4 bytes.

Comment: I don't think those my.cnf settings are an accurate replacement for the `SET NAMES`.

Comment: I didn't add that abut my cnf - some editor here did that. Bad habit if you ask me.     (insert paragraph break - oh right you can't add one of the most semantically useful styling breaks)            I don't know about utf8mb4 being *required* for chinese - it's not-  the database has been taking Chinese input (and Japanese and Korean) perfectly fine with uft8 for the past two years and outputting to PDF and web - and lots of people have read the output to verify it was fine.